# Which Bootstrap3 new column classes should I use?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How are we supposed to use the column classes (.col-xs-,.col-sm-,.col-md-,.col-lg-) ?

I mean, I'm working on a web application that primarily targets tablets but it must also work well in smartphones and desktops. From the bootstrap docs, I see that each one of these classes is aimed at one of the device types/sizes. So... which one do I choose? I don't think I'm supposed to create a different version of the pages for each device..am I?

Thanks.

Comment: Try resizing the browser to see how columns automatically react to the screen size in the examples to get a better understanding of how it works. And remember you can use multiple column classes for the same div.

Comment: I did that but I admit that using several classes didn't cross my mind..duh. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you absolutely don't need to create different versions of your page.

All those different classes do is allow you to define your columns across different resolutions.

If you don't want that level of granular control that the bootstrap provides for setting columns across all the breakpoints, why not start with the `col-md-*` columns and see what that gets you, you might be satisfied with just that. If you decide you want columns adjusted for different resolutions, you can absolutely dive in and apply those additional classes.

Answer (score 1):

Go to [this page](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) and try resizing the width. You'll see that at different widths the columns get arranged differently.

You typically wouldn't choose between the different types (`col-xs-*`, `col-sm-*`, `col-md-*`,
 `col-lg-*`). You'd typically include one or more of them.

To start you can just use `col-md-*` everywhere. If later when using the site with a smaller screen you see something not laid out the way you want, you can add more classes (`col-xs-*`, `col-sm-*`). But you wouldn't necessarily remove the `col-md-*` classes you'd already picked.

Answer (score 1):

If tablet is your primary target, consider what type of layout you're trying to achieve in terms of number of horizontal columns.

For example on a tablet you want 3 columns across, so you'd use `.col-sm-*`..

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">..</div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">..</div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">..</div>
</div>
```

**This will also appear as 3 columns on anything wider/larger** such as desktop, laptop. Therefore you only need to use classes for the smallest device you want to support.

On devices smaller than `.col-sm-*` tablets this layout will stack vertically, and all columns will change to 100% width. If you want to maintain the 3 columns even on smartphones you would add the `.col-xs-*` class..

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">..</div>
     <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">..</div>
     <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">..</div>
</div>
```

Check out this for different scenarios: http://bootply.com/77634